# Add a File Extension to a Group of Files from MacOS terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a directory of many directories of files with various exertion. I would like to add (for the extension .mid) to each of the files, if it is not already a .mid file.

```
for f in  /Users/username/junk/*/
    do
    if [ -d $f ]; then
        cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f
        for file in *.*; 
        do
            if [ "${file: -4}" != ".mid" ]; then
                do mv "$i" "$i.mid"; done
            fi
        done
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

I'd like to have .mid files to be excluded from renaming. If a file is "sad54music.sty", this will remained to "sad54music.sty".

When I excuse the bash, I get the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS

Comment: You have a loop skeleton. Now add into that loop 1) a test for the extensions `.mid` and `.sty` and if the file is a directory - continue if so. 2) Then use that loop which should work on a single directory and google how to loop in Bash over then result of `find` That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for the commend. I tried your approach and edited the OP. Would you please let me know what I am doing wrong now?

Comment: If your paths are not absolute, when you do `cd "$f"` you need also `cd <the previous directory>` or `cd -`. Otherwise you'll be in that folder the next loop. If your paths are absolute, it could work. The `else continue`  does nothing.

Comment: `.mid files to be excluded from renaming. If a file is "sad54music.sty",` - well `.sty` file is not `.mid` file so you described it should be renamed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        if [ "${file: -4}" != ".mid" ]; then
            do mv "$file" "$file.mid"; done
        fi
```

There is no `do ... done` inside `if`. `if` has `then` and `fi`. Just:

```
        if [ "${file: -4}" != ".mid" ]; then
            mv "$file" "$file.mid"
        fi
```

I would just `find` all the files in the second subfolder of `/Users/username/junk/` that are a regex `*.*` but are not `*.mid` and then move them with `mid` suffix. Your script could be just:

```
find /Users/username/junk/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f \
    -name '*.*' -not -name '*.mid' -exec sh -c 'mv -v "$1" "$1.mid"' -- {} \;
```